# Does net/ssh/shell work with Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby, net-ssh

I am trying the sample code from: http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/n/net-ssh-shell-0.2.0/README_rdoc.html

```
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/ssh/shell'

Net::SSH::start('host', 'user', :password=>'password') do |ssh|
  puts ssh.exec!("hostname")
  ssh.shell do |sh|
    sh.execute "cd /usr/local"
    sh.execute "pwd"
    sh.execute "export FOO=bar"
    sh.execute "echo $FOO"
    p=sh.execute "grep dont /tmp/notexist"
    puts "Exit Status:#{p.exit_status}"
    puts "Command Executed:#{p.command}"
  end
end
```

I do pass in my password, and confirmed that I am logged in by testing with `ssh.exec!("hostname")`.
I am expecting some output from the `pwd` and `echo` commands, but I don't see it. In addition, the program/script just hangs at the end.  I am using Ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15) [i386-mingw32] on Windows.  I tested against the SSH server on OS X, and Ubuntu.

Here my output.  The trace is from me doing Ctrl-C:

```
C:\sb>ruby test.sh
Exit Status:
Command Executed:grep dont /tmp/notexist
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/ruby_compat.rb:22:
in `select': Interrupt
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/ruby_compat.rb:22:in `io_select'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:201:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `block in loop'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `loop'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:161:in `loop'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:110:in `close'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.1.4/lib/net/ssh.rb:191:in `start'
        from test.sh:5:in `<main>'
```

Comment: What sample code at that link?  It might be good to simply show the code you are using, rather than simply give a page.

Comment: Oops! Updated link and sample code. Thanks :)

Comment: I presumed 1.9.3 based on the 193 in the filename - the API version of 1.9.3 is 1.9.1 and no-one should be using 1.9.1 anymore, it's not supported.

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15) [i386-mingw32] .  I took 1.9.1 incorrectly from the trace

Comment: I have the same problem here. It is hanging.

Comment: I am not using net/ssh/shell anymore, just net/ssh.  My new script looks something like this:
require 'net/ssh'

Net::SSH::start('server', 'user', :password=>'password') do |ssh|
    channel = ssh.open_channel do |channel|
        channel.on_data do |ch, data|
        print data
    end
 
    channel.exec("bash -l") do |ch, success|
        ch.send_data "echo $PATH\n"
        ch.send_data "exit\n"
        end
    end
end

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is that you will not see output except for what you have determined you want output for.  Then you need to direct the return of the command to be rendered or output, in the normal ways.

In this code, there are only two lines of output, and they are:

`puts "Exit Status:#{p.exit_status}"`

`puts "Command Executed:#{p.command}"`

I believe you are seemingly not getting progression on the program due to it waiting for a password.  When I run this code and have key-only ssh access, it continues on.  When it is connecting to my local system, it is seemingly waiting for my password.

This is a `ssh` session, you will need to exit the session at some point, when you want to leave it.

Still you want output from the session you will need to do the same thing as you do for your output on hostname.  You used puts.  You also do the same for the last two I mentioned above.

It isn't hanging, it simply is not told you are done with the secure shell.

Comment: +1. "you are seemingly not getting progression on the program due to it waiting for a password." This is a common problem in ssh/telnet sessions. Many people will say to use a ssh key, but that isn't the right solution. Check for the password prompt when you connect but don't hang indefinitely in case you don't see it. That'll handle having a ssh key and not.

Comment: I don't think it's waiting for my password.  I passed in my password.  I also tried at the end sh.execute("exit") and got some other kind of error.  sh.execute return a Process object.  I haven't been able to get the output from the Process object (I tried using on_output). I am going to try to use channel in the Net::SSH built-in library instead.

Comment: But you get output on everything else you have asked for.  And I believe you still need to add an exit command as well to close out the shell.